# App crashes on changing theme under styles

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme, android-styles, android-compatibility

**My Android App :**

*Target AP*I:**22**

*Min API*:**15**

*Device* run on :API level **22**

I don't understand this whole theme concept ,

In my `manifest.xml` ,I have set  `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

and all activities use this theme

Now my understanding is that they all use the theme called `AppTheme` which I can now define by extending other themes inside my `styles.xml`

In my `styles.xml`

I have this

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

My understanding is that  `AppCompat` themes allow us to use newer(say material themes) on  older devices also .
I run this app on API Level 22 and API Level 15 , it works fine

Now when i change it to

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

It gives a warning saying this theme  can be used only on API 21 or above which is correct , now when  I ignore the warning and run it in on API 22 it crashes.
Why?

Also I tried to make AppTheme's parent as Holo , Light etc ,all of them crash the App , why , please explain?

All of these end up crashing the App

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Translucent">
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
```

Why do these not work , Holo was introduced in 15 right?

I am using 22 ,

and can you please elaborate the difference between 
Theme....., BaseTheme....,Android..... themeName

And i am running android studio 1.3 and using the latest versions(Stable) of the SDK,SDK build and SDK-Platform tools.
Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry , I found the issue , My activity was extending AppCompatActivity instead of the general activity ,I get it now

Comment: So what that mean ??

Comment: @Pugazh  I got this too in android studio 4. Changing  from `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()` to `class MainActivity : Activity()` solved this error for me.

Comment: @Guus , Thanks for sharing a solution

Answer (score 0):

When ever working with custom styles you have to take care of the parent you are providing. Try to change the parent theme and it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the hosting device theme from dark to light or light to dark. I had a similar problem by doing that solved my thing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).